# Can I calculate the ideal rotation and translation to match two sets of points in 3d space?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two sets of data: X, Y, Z actual coordinates and X, Y, Z ideal coordinates.
Assuming that the origin is zero I want to find the perfect translation and rotation that I need to apply to the origin for the points to match as closely as possible. Basically to realign the origin.

[Actual and ideal coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd8xz.png)

Eyeballing the actual and ideal coordinates we can see that we need to go about : X:-11, Y:-5, Z:+20 and rotations about +- 1 deg.

I have tried Kabisch algorithm, and ICP (without o3d as am still not able to install it) and I got results that don`t reflect the reality: Offsets without + or - sign, verry big rotations compared to the data.

I am struggling with this for a few days as is a part of a personal project and I don`t know if it`s possible or my small brain doesn`t fully understand how to use the algorithms.

Comment: Would this be a regression question? I.e. if you can express the rotation as a matrix and find the result that minimises error?

Comment: I have tried using regression and  converting the rotation matrix in angle rotations, but also this approach gave me flawed results.

Comment: I did not propertly converted the rotation. This works:

``def umeyama_alignment(actual_coords, ideal_coords):
    actual_centroid = np.mean(actual_coords, axis=0)
    ideal_centroid = np.mean(ideal_coords, axis=0)

    actual_centered = actual_coords - actual_centroid
    ideal_centered = ideal_coords - ideal_centroid

    H = np.dot(actual_centered.T, ideal_centered)

    U, S, Vt = np.linalg.svd(H)

    R = np.dot(Vt.T, U.T)

    if np.linalg.det(R) < 0:
        Vt[-1, :] *= -1
        R = np.dot(Vt.T, U.T)

    T = ideal_centroid - np.dot(actual_centroid, R)``

Comment: use the edit button to add additional info. Code doesn't display in comments

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.